# Hibernate @OneToOne gets a NullPointer Exception

Tags: hibernate-annotations

I am reviewing my Java skills and your support to the community is amazing, your tips have helped me a lot.

I am stuck in a Hibernate @OneToOne configuration, it is a very simple design and code but I can´t find the error. I´d really appreciate your help.

This is the user.java code, the user_id is generated by an autoincrement column at MySQL. I have omitted hash() and equals() code for simplicity. Hibernate understands the User class but something is missing to get to the Address class that is at the other side of the relationship.

Any help would be very appreciated.
Thank you

1) This is the user.java:

```
package myPackage;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="user1")

public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3271213543123246487L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="user_id")
    private Integer user_id;

    @Column(name="user_name", length=100, nullable=false)
    private String user_name;


    @OneToOne (cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private Address myAddress;

    public Integer getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }

    public void setUser_id(Integer user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }

    public String getUser_name() {
        return user_name;
    }

    public void setUser_name(String user_name) {
        this.user_name = user_name;
    }

    public Address getMyAddress() {
        return myAddress;
    }

    public void setMyAddress(Address myAddress) {
        this.myAddress = myAddress;
    }   
}
```

2) This is the Address.java code:

```
package myPackage;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter;

@Entity
@Table(name="address1")

public class Address implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3605176021936036836L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="address_ibfk_2")
    @org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator(name="address_ibfk_2", 
        strategy="foreign",parameters =@Parameter(name="property",value="user1"))
    @Column(name="user_id")
    private Integer user_id; 

    @Column(name="address_line1", length=100, nullable=false)
    private String address_line1;

    public String getAddress_line1() {
        return address_line1;
    }

    public void setAddress_line1(String address_line1) {
        this.address_line1 = address_line1;
    }   
}
```

3) This is the very simple TestUser class

```
public class TestUser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Session mySession = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    System.out.println("Connection status"+mySession.isConnected());
    System.out.println("Session status"+mySession.isOpen());

    Transaction myTransaction = mySession.beginTransaction();           

    try {

        User myUser = new User();
        Address myAddress = new Address();

        myUser.setUser_name("TesteO2O");
        myAddress.setAddress_line1("Rua A");
        myUser.setMyAddress(myAddress);

        mySession.save(myUser);

        myTransaction.commit();
        System.out.println("myUser saved sucessfully");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        myTransaction.rollback();
    } finally {
        mySession.close();
    }
}
```

}

4) This is the hibernate.cfg.xml config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
   <session-factory>

        <!--MySQL Config-->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/p2pl_dev?serverTimezone=UTC</property>
        <property name="connection.username">xyz</property>
        <property name="connection.password">blabla</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!--Connection Pool Config: max_statements cached, idle time in seconds-->
        <property name="c3po.min_size">2</property>
        <property name="c3po.max_size">3</property>
        <property name="c3po.timeout">300</property>
        <property name="c3po.max_stamentes">50</property>
        <property name="c3po.idle_test_period">3000</property>

        <!--Debug Config, show_sql=console, format_sql=legible -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>           
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>         
        <property name="generate_statistics">true</property>        
        <property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>       

        <!-- Classes -->
        <mapping class="myPackage.User"/>
        <mapping class="myPackage.Address"/>

   </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

5) Finally the error trace

```
Hibernate: 
    /* insert myPackage.User
        */ insert 
        into
            user1
            (user_name) 
        values
            (?)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getPropertyValue(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:650)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getPropertyValue(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4736)
    at org.hibernate.id.ForeignGenerator.generate(ForeignGenerator.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:209)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:684)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:676)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$5.cascade(CascadingActions.java:235)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:460)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:294)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:209)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:715)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:707)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:702)
    at myPackage.TestUser.main(TestUser.java:26)
```